# counting the number days between two days using java ,dates from HTML input tags

Tags: java, datetime

I have use the following code for calculating the difference between two dates that had been taken form the HTML INPUT TAG, and the method is called the method in service method of servlet ,

```
public static long daysBetween (Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {  
      Calendar date = (Calendar) startDate.clone(); 

      long daysBetween = 0;  
      while (date.before(endDate)) {  
        date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        daysBetween++;  
      }  
      return daysBetween;  
    }
```

Then in the calling method during passing parameters it raised an exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.util.Calendar

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Your algoritm lacks finesse. Try this:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public static long daysBetween (Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(
        endDate.getTimeInMillis() - startDate.getTimeInMillis()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following code:

```
long difference = endDate.getTime().getTime() - startDate.getTime().getTime();
```

This will return the difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Check where you are calling daysBetween() from. Are you passing in `java.util.Date` instead of `java.util.Calendar`?